# How to remove occasional pop-up messages from the provider

Tags: motorola-milestone

My Milestone is producing pop-up messages every half an hour with "your credits are low please add more credits". It is really annoying. Is there any way to block them?

Answer (score 1):

Not without either loading a custom ROM that doesn't have these popups. These are probably "features" added for your carrier, so a more "generic" ROM would probably stop them.